# SharePoint sandbox event receivers throwing Unknown Status Module: 33 Message: 134 error

Tags: events, sharepoint-2010, sandbox

I have a sandboxed solution with event receivers connected to a document library using the ListUrl attribute. Working with the library from the UI or the Server-side Object Model API running inside the SharePoint IIS worker process produces no errors. The event receivers are called and everything works as expected. Using the Client Object Model API also works fine. But when working with the library from a console application running outside the worker process using the Server-side Object Model API I run into problems. 
Making any changes to the library items which trigger an event receiver using the Server-side Object Model API results in an error similar to the following:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException was unhandled
  Message=Unknown Status Module: 33 Message: 134
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint
  ErrorCode=-2130575223
  NativeErrorMessage=FAILED hr detected (hr = 0x81020089)

  NativeStackTrace=""
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 30
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
       Message=<nativehr>0x81020089</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Unknown Status Module: 33 Message: 134
       Source=""
       ErrorCode=-2130575223
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)
            at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)
       InnerException:
```

I get this error even if the event receivers don't do anything. Debugging shows that the event receivers never even get called. If I disable the event receivers before making the updates or remove the event receivers entirely from the sandbox solution the console application completes successfully without any errors.

Any help in resolving this error is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case event receiver was activatee inside a wrong feature.